# Q: Service Worker works in browser but not as PWA

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I am working on my first PWA and started from scratch. When i start it in Chrome it works fine and caches al the static files, and when i go offline it still works. My problem is when i download the pwa and then go offline it doesn't cache it for some reason. I can't really find some solution for it so i try to get some insight from here.

Here is my Code:

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'static_cache_v1'
const staticAssets = [
    './',
    './style.css',
    './main.js'
];
self.addEventListener('install', async event => {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
    cache.addAll(staticAssets);
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', async event => {
    const req = event.request;
    event.respondWith(cacheFirst(req));
});
async function cacheFirst(req) {
    const cachedResponse = await caches.match(req);
    return cachedResponse || fetch(req);
}
self.addEventListener('activate', async event => {

});
```

You can see my example here:
[pwa](https://www.brancoturk.com/pwa)

Comment: hi, your question is not cleat for me, not able to understand can you please elaborate

Comment: Hello Aji, my question is what i am missing in my code to make it work offline on mobile as a PWA and browser instead of only the browser. Looks like it does not cache when it is installed on my phone.

Comment: does it working fine in Desktop, did you try adding the PWA and install to desktopn and try in offline

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Code, 
I have implemented and was working fine

- Make sure you added the service worker is in root-path
- Make sure you application is https ( localhost also will work fine ), no http site will have the Service worker functionality

> ```
> var cacheName = 'bemna-LAstLAP-2013';
>
>
> self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
>     event.waitUntil(
>         caches.open('v1').then(function (cache) {
>             return cache.addAll([
>                 '/',
>                // all file which you need to cache at start - static caching 
>             ]);
>         })
>     );
> });
>
> // To delete the old chache if name changed it will delete old chache 
> self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
>     console.info('Event: Activate');
>     event.waitUntil(
>         caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
>             return Promise.all(
>                 cacheNames.map((cache) => {
>                     if (cache !== cacheName) {
>                         return caches.delete(cache);
>                     }
>                 })
>             );
>         })
>     );
> });
>
> self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
>                 event.respondWith(
>                     // Cache first approch 
>                     caches.open(cacheName).then(function (cache) {
>                         return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
>                             return response || fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
>                                 cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
>                                 return response;
>                             });
>                         });
>                     })
>                 );
>
> });
>
> self.addEventListener('sync', function (event) {
>     if (event.tag == 'myFirstSync') {
>         console.log("synching")
>
>     }
>     console.log("test");
> });
> ```

- Now set the manifest file in the application , while setting manifest please cross check the **Scope and start_url** are correct
- Destop PWA installable will support in ( Version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit) i tried in this

> ```
> {
>     "short_name": "Chat",
>     "name": "Chat App",
>     "icons": [
>       {
>         "src": "images/web_application.png",
>         "type": "image/png",
>         "sizes": "192x192"
>       },
>       {
>         "src": "images/web_application.png",
>         "type": "image/png",
>         "sizes": "512x512"
>       }
>     ],
>     "start_url": "./#comments",
>     "background_color": "#3367D6",
>     "display": "standalone",
>     "scope": "/",
>     "theme_color": "#3367D6"
>   }
> ```

Once you set the manifest to get the install option banner, you have to enable few features in chrome.

- Open a new tab in chrome and type **chrome://flags/** in browser
- Search for **Desktop PWAs** and **App Banners** and enable both
- Once you enable re-launch the browser and refresh the page
- You will see a banner on top asking to install the app to desktop if you didn't see there go the the option panel ( 3 dots in right most ) you can see an option for install you website.

Thats it now your application will have a icon to launch and it will work as a native /  desktop application

Hope this will work for you.